# How can I send ctrl+x with Sendkeys?

Tags: c#

How can I send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> using `Sendkeys.Send` in C#?

Comment: What are you using this to do?

Comment: `SendKeys` is not a reliable way to accomplish anything.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Auto close down an old win32 app that uses Ctrl+x to quit

Comment: If the old app is a console app, then the best thing to do is get the standard input stream when you launch the process and use that to send CTRL-X.  Depending on what the app does and the situation when you're trying to force it to exit, you could also resort to Process.Kill().

Comment: Duplicated question here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144202/what-is-an-alternative-to-sendkeys-for-closing-a-legacy-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SendKeys.Send("^X")
```

.. but SendKeys.. yuck.. :-)

Comment: definitely agree with 'yuck!' !!

Answer (score 4):

```
SendKeys.Send("^X")
```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

um.. can be this?

```
SendKeys.Send("^x");
```