# What is an alternative to Sendkeys for closing a legacy application?

Tags: c#

I want my C# program to shut down a certain legacy application before proceeding. The legacy app may be shut down immediately using ctrl+x. I could do this using Sendkeys, but I've been told that sendkeys can be a little flaky. Is there an alternative way for me to send this key combination and shut the legacy app down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other options include:
[System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)
[System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx)

If the latter works, use it. If not, and you lose nothing by killing the process directly, then Kill().

Comment: I don't think that would be a good idea...since we have no idea what this legacy program does, you could end up `kill`ing the data associated with it, say it is tied to for example dBase or paradox or clipper, o.g.k, is the corruption of that worth it to do this?

Comment: Hence the caveat "if... you lose nothing by killing the process directly."

Comment: How will you even know you loose nothing? Just because it works once is no gurantee it will work all of the time.  I think CloseMainWindow is safe, but I would never suggest anyone use Kill.

Comment: My legacy application is calc.exe and I can't kill it? I'm just playing devil's advocate, here. As was mentioned in a previous comment, "we have no idea what this legacy program does." I provided two options, and encourage the use of the "safe" one. Should I go all VB on the OP and conceal the existence of `Kill()`?

Answer (score 3):

If you know what the window's title is on the caption bar, such as 'Foo', then you can use p/invoke to find the window and get the handle from it '[FindWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html)'. Once you get the handle, then you can use '[SendMessage](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html)' to that handle sending a '[WM_KEYUP](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=WM_KEYUP&namespace=[All])' that denotes Ctrl+X together.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: What is the advantage of Ctrl+X over and CloseMainWindow()? Complexity?

Comment: CloseMainWindow() is for, if you instantiate the process using the system.Diagnostics.Process class, as per the link you included, it cannot be used for any other process outside of the application.

Comment: This is also implying that the OP has used the Process class to shell out and run the legacy app, but that is not the case!

Comment: I don't see where that is implied. A reference to the Process can be acquired more easily in c# than can be implemented a SendMessage.

Comment: Using the handle obtained from 'FindWindow' and sending the message is much easier and efficient instead of iterating through the process list (which can be quite big in terms of looping, how many processes are running on your machine...and trying to find the process's id to kill it) and that is what the OP was looking for, I hope! :)

Answer (score 3):

If this is a GUI application.  It may also respond to Alt+F4 via SendKeys.

Unlike ctrl+x, Alt+F4 will not depend on which window has focus. This is a standard accelerator for windows applications and most older GUI applications will support it. The main reason SendKey is considered flakey is because keystrokes get delivered to the focus window, which may or may not understand them.  But Alt+F4 is an accelerator, so it should work regardless of which window has focus.

If you can get the handle to the main window.  (use `FindWindow` if you don't have it already).  You can

```
PostMessage(hwndApp, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
```

This is equivalent to choosing the close option from the system menu on the window.  `SendMessage` should work as well, but PostMessage is safer since your application doesn't wait for the message to be delivered.

[WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360(VS.85).aspx)